# Verify success of Luence Indexing operation

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

Currently an index has x documents written to it using an `IndexWriter`. After x have been written a check is made to ensure that all is okay on the persisted index.

```
var reader = IndexReader.Open(path);

If(!reader.NumDocs() == ExpectedCount)
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? Opening an `IndexReader` constantly has to be expensive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/03/transactional-lucene.html

> Lucene implements ACID properties: 
>   - Atomicity: when you make changes
>   (adding, removing documents) in an IndexWriter session, and then
>   commit, either all (if the commit succeeds) or none (if the commit
>   fails) of your changes will be visible, never something in-between.

I think there is no good reason to doubt the above contract.

Comment: I was thinking the same. I was going to add to the question "or is there even a need to this operation". If the indexing did not throw, it seems safe to assume all was okay.